# Change of Basis in Game Development

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

I recently went back to re-learning some bits of linear algebra: change of basis.

And, as an exercise, I decided to revisit a video game mechanic: portals.
[As this youtuber puts it](https://youtu.be/cWpFZbjtSQg?si=wxsPKmOK5bu7wlUu&t=73), the math behind it is that you want to know the Camera's position relative to the Blue Portal and then that position relative to the Red Portal.

From what I understood of Change of Basis, I would translate this to transforming the vector $X_C$ from the Camera basis $C$ into vector $X_B$ -- its corresponding vector in the Blue Portal basis $B$. Finally, using that to find vector $X_R$ which would correspond to that vector in the Red Portal's basis $R$.

From here I applied the change of basis formula twice.

$$ B \times X_B = C \times X_C $$
$$ X_B = B^{-1} \times C \times X_C $$
$$ R \times X_R = B \times X_B $$
$$ X_R = R^{-1} \times B \times X_B $$

The problem is that if I replace $X_B$ in the last equation with the second one I get:
$$ X_R = R^{-1} \times B \times B^{-1} \times C \times X_C = R^{-1} \times C \times X_C $$
This makes no sense as it no longer even takes $B$ into consideration.

The video seems to end up with a matrix that would correspond to:
$$ R \times B^{-1} \times C $$

So, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: change of basis twice is not quite what you want to do. Let the canonical basis (i.e. that with matrix $1$) be $W$ i.e.
$$R\times X_R = B\times X_B = C\times X_C = X_W$$
You can see that all the change of basis formula does is compute which vectors in each basis represent that *same* canonical vector, but we actually want to compute a different canonical vector from that of the camera vector: the one that's been transported by the portal. The key idea is that the transported vector $Y$ is the same locally in the red portal's space as the camera's is in the blue portal's space, i.e.
$$Y_R = X_B$$
This is *not* a change of basis. It is an isometric map of blue portal's space onto red portal's space. We then we apply change of basis on $Y$
$$R\times Y_R = Y_W$$
$$Y_R = R^{-1}\times Y_W$$
and change of basis on $X$
$$B \times X_B = C\times X_C$$
$$X_B = B^{-1}\times C\times X_C$$
Combined giving
$$R^{-1}\times Y_W = B^{-1}\times C\times X_C$$
$$Y_W = R\times B^{-1}\times C\times X_C$$
By linearity we can apply this equation over the identity matrix to get
$$Y = R\times B^{-1}\times C$$